# How to display array inside array values in angular 8?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, angular8

I am new to angular and trying to display array inside array values in table

this is my json array and wanted to show it in rows

```
{
  "data": {
    "Influencer": [
      {
        "clickDetails": [
          [
            {
              "clk_counter": "1",
              "social_type": "14"
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              "clk_counter": "32",
              "social_type": "1"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my html code, I'm passing **data.Influencer** array to **resultSet** but it's not working as it's showing only the first array from **clickDetails** as I set **data.clickDetails[0]** in *ngFor so another array is in **data.clickDetails[1]** I don't know how to show that

```
<tbody *ngIf="resultSet.length>0 ">
 <tr role="row" class="odd" *ngFor="let data of resultSet">
   <td>
       <span *ngFor="let clickd of data.clickDetails[0]">
           <span *ngIf="clickd.social_type==1"> 
               {{clickd.clk_counter}}
           </span>
       </span>
   </td>
   <td>
       <span *ngFor="let clickd of data.clickDetails[0]">
           <span *ngIf="clickd.social_type==2"> 
               {{clickd.clk_counter}
           </span>
       </span>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

**resultSet** having **data.Influencer** object

Please Help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the nested array of data. You need to loop through the nested array again using `*ngFor` loop instead of passing array index. Here is the sample code.

```
<tbody>
  <tr role="row" class="odd" *ngFor="let data of resultSet">
    <td>
      <span *ngFor="let clickd of data.clickDetails">
        <span *ngFor="let item of clickd">
          <span *ngIf="item.social_type==1" > 
            {{item.clk_counter}}
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```